# Above the barrier voltage does a pn junction behave ohmically?

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

I understand that below the barrier voltage no current flows, and once the required voltage is met the current rises exponentially, in accordance with the ideal diode equation. However at voltages above this region (~1.0-1.5v for a silicon diode) it appears that here is a linear relationship between V and I. Is this correct? [Edit: for a real diode]

Comment: Theoretically or for a real diode?

Comment: For a real diode

Comment: You can always find a ESR (equivalent series resistance) for any device, so for a small enough range, you will have a linear I-V-relationship. The less ideal the diode is, the wider the range you will see this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real diodes have a resistive component to the behavior, not described by the Shockley equation.

Of course if you have 1.5V (forward bias) across a silicon diode at room temperature (or higher) it is conducting a lot of current. At very high currents (typically well above the rated continuous current) the resistance can dominate.

Here is a SPICE model for a 1N4004 from [Onsemi](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/supportDoc.do?type=models&rpn=1N4004):

.MODEL D1n4004rl d
+IS=5.31656e-08 RS=0.0392384 N=2 EG=0.6
+XTI=0.05 BV=400 IBV=5e-08 CJO=1e-11
+VJ=0.7 M=0.5 FC=0.5 TT=1e-09
+KF=0 AF=1

You can see there is a series resistance RS in the model of about 39m ohm. If you pulse 10A through this 1A diode, the resistance will drop 392mV.